# Install a custom module in magento 2 stable

Tags: magento2

Downloaded the M2 from magentocommerce with sample data. I have custom module which i developed locally on M2-rc 2.0. My question is that now how can i install module and where i place the custom module as there is no code folder in app directory and all the magento modules are in vendor folder. Also i dont want to create a repo for my module. Also i want to put my module in vendor folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create the `app/code/YourNameSpace/ModuleName` folder yourself. Make sure, that your `composer.json` in the project root contains the line

```
    "files": [
        "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
    ]
```

in the autoload section (see https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition/blob/master/composer.json#L42) which is responsible for loading modules which are not installed via composer.

Comment: thanks for help. Also if i want to install module using composer then where i place the files?

Comment: Then you need to make a own repository for that module, add your module to the `composer.json` and call `composer.phar update`